# Left-click brings up view port shading

Tags: 3d-view

I recently joined blender and while I was making a GFX for a friend the left-click button suddenly changed to this.

[image]

Sorry if I didn't explain this well.

Comment: What is your key map set as?

Comment: Which part?  If you're talking about the select, it's left.

Comment: Did you possibly assign a shortcut something a shortcut of left click intentionally?

Comment: No I didn't assign a shortcut that I know of.

Comment: For some odd reason this has happened to a student of mine several times. When we go to her keymaps we find Context enum menu mapping mapped to left click. She has not did that herself but it comes back even after reinstall etc. Taking the tick off the context enum menu or changing it works. Hope this helps someone else annoyed by it

Comment: just change your key map to blender default or do a factory reset. blender has so many shortkeys that in the beginning it is common to reassign them by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

For some odd reason this has happened to a student of mine several times. When we go to her keymaps we find `Context enum menu` mapping mapped to left click. She has not did that herself but it comes back even after reinstall etc. I have no idea why but it happens.

Taking the tick off the context enum menu or changing it to something else works (for example the normal <kbd>E</kbd>).

Go to
*Edit > Preferences > Keymap*, search for `Context Enum` or `Left Mouse` to find it.

[image: Preferences]

Your keymap might look like this

[image: Wrong]

It should look like this

[image: Right]